# Firebase Remote Config REST API not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

In our Android app after Firebase Config update to `16.3.0` our app stopped receiving config updates due to 403 error on debug project.
We followed [REST API migration guideline](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-rest#before_you_begin_enable_the_rest_api) and it started working.
On our live project REST api was enabled and we did not have to switch it on. But it responded with 403 anyway after SDK update.
After going back to `16.1.3`, it started working, but I don't want to downgrade but better to find the issue.
What might be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We received response from Firebase support team, confirming that **there is a bug in `Firebase config SDK 16.3.0` version.**

To avoid this issue, use `Firebase config SDK 16.1.3` until next library version.